# bigquery command line - bq show vs MySQL show create table

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-console

To find a schema of a BigQuery table, I can use
   bq show

But
   bq show
will display the the schema info in this format

- date: string
                  |- channel_id: string
                  |- video_id: string
                  |- asset_id: string
                  |- claimed_status: string
                  |- uploader_type: string
                  |- country_code: string

But what I need is the schema file format that I can just copy and paste to BigQuery Cloud Console to use to create a new table directly.

Such as

```
channel_id: string, video_id: string, asset_id: string, claimed_status:string, uploader_type: string, country_code: string
```

Like MySQL show create table statement, the result of it should be "copy and paste" to create a new table.

Any bq command can do that? I cannot find one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
bq --format=prettyjson show
```

Example output:

```
  "schema": {
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "a", 
        "type": "TIMESTAMP"
      }
    ]
  },
```

And copy the output array to the cloud console:

```
    [
      {
        "name": "a", 
        "type": "TIMESTAMP"
      }
    ]
```

For more compact output, you can also use --format=json